# EXACT function return "#N/A" error in array formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I apply the formula to the range B3:B7 it works perfectly. When I apply the formula to the range B4:C4 it not works perfectly. The formula detects lowercase letters in the range.

Vertical: `=IF(SUM(EXACT(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(B3:B7,LEN(B3:B7)-SEARCH(" ",B3:B7,1)),2),""),{"Bb","Yb","Zb","Eb","Pb","Tb","Gb","Mb","Kb","bB","yB","zB","eB","pB","tB","gB","mB","kB","bb","yb","zb","eb","pb","tb","gb","mb","kb"})+0)>=1,"LOWERCASE DETECT","CORRECT")`

Horizontal: `=IF(SUM(EXACT(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(B4:C4,LEN(B4:C4)-SEARCH(" ",B4:C4,1)),2),""),{"Bb","Yb","Zb","Eb","Pb","Tb","Gb","Mb","Kb","bB","yB","zB","eB","pB","tB","gB","mB","kB","bb","yb","zb","eb","pb","tb","gb","mb","kb"})+0)>=1,"LOWERCASE DETECT","CORRECT")`

formula return #N/A error.

```
=IF(SUM({0,0,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A})>=1,"LOWERCASE DETECT","CORRECT")
```

i tried capture #N/A with IFNA() but unsuccessfully:

```
=SUM(IFNA(EXACT(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(B4:C4,LEN(B4:C4)-SEARCH(" ",B4:C4,1)),2),""),{"Bb","Yb","Zb","Eb","Pb","Tb","Gb","Mb","Kb","bB","yB","zB","eB","pB","tB","gB","mB","kB","bb","yb","zb","eb","pb","tb","gb","mb","kb"})+0,0))
```

formula return 0

```
=IF(SUM({0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0})>=1,"LOWERCASE DETECT","CORRECT")
```

Again unsuccessfully the formula does not count. Why doesn't the formula work in the horizontal direction?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do, determine if there is any lowercase letter in those cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save some typing with:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(EXACT(UPPER(RIGHT(B4:C4,2)),RIGHT(B4:C4,2))))),"LOWERCASE DETECT","CORRECT")
```

[image]

---

The error with your formula is that you created a horizontal array comparing it to a horizontal array, which would need to be the same number and does a one to one comparison.

You need to transpose the array of value:

```
=IF(SUM(EXACT(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(B4:C4,LEN(B4:C4)-SEARCH(" ",B4:C4,1)),2),""),TRANSPOSE({"Bb","Yb","Zb","Eb","Pb","Tb","Gb","Mb","Kb","bB","yB","zB","eB","pB","tB","gB","mB","kB","bb","yb","zb","eb","pb","tb","gb","mb","kb"}))+0)>=1,"LOWERCASE DETECT","CORRECT")
```

[image]

Comment: @dwirony it is an array type formula in that it will iterate the ranges, but it does not require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: @Scott Craner work for me but when type different letter except "b" formula give TRUE value. that’s why I made the rule {"Bb","Yb","Zb","Eb","Pb","Tb","Gb","Mb","Kb","bB","yB","zB","eB","pB","tB","gB","mB","kB","bb","yb","zb","eb","pb","tb","gb","mb","kb"}

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks it works perfectly for me, i'm developing one long formula this is just one part of it. can you give me your email address to contact you privately? i would like to share it with you.